# How to update immutable List to get a new List

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an immutable `Map` like the following

```
var mapA = Map({
  listA: List.of({
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name A',
    selected: false
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name B',
    selected: false
  })
});
```

I want to update the key `selected` within the list. As per immutable.js docs for `list.update`.

> Returns a new List with an updated value at index with the return
>   value of calling updater

However, if I do this

```
var listB = mapA.get('listA').update(1, function (item) {
    item.selected = true;
    return item;
});
```

and, check the object equality, it gives me `true`.

```
console.log(listB === x.get('listA')); // true
```

What am I doing wrong here? Isn't that how immutable.js is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a **mutable** value inside an immutable list. For the list, the object doesn't change, because `oldObject === newObject` is still true.

Here is a simplified example:

```
> var obj = {};
> var list = Immutable.List.of(obj);
> list2 = list.update(0, function(obj) { obj.foo = 42; return obj;});
> list2.get(0)
Object { foo: 42 }
> obj
Object { foo: 42 }
> list.get(0) === list2.get(0)
true
```

To solve this, in addition to also update the map (if you want that), you have to either

- Clone the object on update
- Use a Map instead of an object
- Probably best in this case: Use a [**record**](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) instead of an object

Example:

```
var MyRecord = new Immutable.Record({id: null, name: '', selected: false});

var mapA = Immutable.fromJS({
  listA: [
    new MyRecord({
      id: 1,
      name: 'Name A'
    }),
    new MyRecord({
      id: 2,
      name: 'Name B'
    })
  ]
});

var mapB = mapA.updateIn(['listA', 1], function(record) {
  return record.set('selected', true);
});

console.log(mapB.get('listA') === mapA.get('listA')); // false
```

Comment: Exactly, I just found the same solution while trying it out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You'd need to update the Map too.

```
var mapB = mapA.update('listA', function(item) {
    return item.update(1, function(item) {
        item.selected = true;
        return item;
    });
});
```

Comment: just to add, you could also call `updateIn` with a keypath

Comment: It works though, but at the same time, it mutates the original object as well. Why So!

Comment: @Anchor tried `updateIn`, it doesn't work, `mapA === mapB //true`

Comment: @Салман this doesn't work? 
`var listB = mapA.updateIn(['listA', 1], function(item) {
    item.selected = false;
    return item;
})`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found. The problem is the `List`, it is basically a collection of plain JavaScript objects. Which are mutable.

The solution is simple, I changed the initial object creation to this.

```
var mapA = Immutable.fromJS({
  listA: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name A',
    selected: false
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name B',
    selected: false
  }]
});
```

and now, the following works as expected.

```
var mapB = mapA.setIn(['listA', 1, 'selected'], true);
```